# reinterpret signed long as unsigned in Python

Tags: python

A 64-bit number is unpacked by [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) as signed; how can I reinterpret it as unsigned?

Comment: @Marcin if num < 0: num = struct.unpack("<Q",struct.pack("<q",num))[0]

Comment: Note that python doesn't (natively) have unsigned integers, so you will have to do something slightly clever, like extracting the upper and lower halves of the integer range before adding them to a `decimal` or `long` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
if x < 0:
   x += 2 ** 64
```

or, if you prefer bit twiddling,

```
x &= 2 ** 64 - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this?

```
>>> struct.unpack('L', struct.pack('l', -2235234523))
(18446744071474317093L,)
```